# How do you select most common value, if tie select most recent (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table

> ### Appointments
>
> Apptdate Datetime,
>
> Provider Varchar,
>
> Facility Numeric,
>
> PatientId Numeric,
>
> ApptType Varchar,
>
> Notes Varchar,
>
> etc

I'm trying to get the following

> ### Responsible Provider
>
> PatientID,
>
> ResponsibleProvider

The responsible provider should be the provider seen the most in the last year but if there is a tie such as someone saw two providers each two times in the last year then the most recently seen provider should be listed. I want to use this to find the responsible provider for all patients seen in a timeframe. How can I do that in SQL?

So far I created a temp table that lists patient, the providers they've seen, and the times the patients have seen those providers in the last year. The SQL is below

```
CREATE TABLE #ProviderApptCount(
Patientid Numeric,
Provider Varchar,
Count Numeric,
Mostrecentvisit Date
)

INSERT INTO #ProviderApptCount
SELECT a.PatientId, a.Provider, COUNT(a.Provider), MAX(a.Apptdate)
FROM Appointments a
WHERE a.Apptdate BETWEEN DATEADD(YY, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
    AND a.FacilityId LIKE 2
GROUP BY a.PatientId, a.Provider
```

Again, how do I get the most seen provider and the most recently seen provider if there is a tie for most seen provider? And this list should have each patient seen in a timeframe with the 'Responsible Provider' next to their name if possible.

Sorry for any confusion

Thank you!

Comment: You need to first decide which DBMS you are using. mysql <> sql server.

Comment: If you are using sql server you can do this using ROW_NUMBER. I have answered almost this exact question three or four times today.

Comment: Could you link me to one? For some reason I haven't been able to find it...  Do you use it in conjunction with orderby date? Thank you!                       @SeanLange

Comment: In addition to being able to do this with a ROW_NUMBER() window function, I don't understand why this couldn't be solved by `TOP 1` with an order by the specific columns you want to order by as well...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with ROW_NUMBER but probably top 1 is all you need here. Something like this.

```
SELECT top 1 a.PatientId
    , a.Provider
    , COUNT(a.Provider)
    , a.Apptdate
FROM Appointments a
WHERE a.Apptdate BETWEEN DATEADD(YY, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
    AND a.FacilityId LIKE 2 --Perhaps this should be = instead of LIKE?
GROUP BY a.PatientId
    , a.Provider
    , a.ApptDate
order by COUNT(a.Provider) desc
    , a.Apptdate desc
```

--EDIT--

To be able to retrieve for all patients you would need to implement ROW_NUMBER. Something like this should be pretty close.

```
select x.PatientId
    , x.Provider
    , x.PatientCount
    , x.ApptDate
from 
(
    SELECT a.PatientId
        , a.Provider
        , PatientCount = COUNT(a.Provider) over(partition by a.PatientId)
        , a.Apptdate
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by a.PatientId order by COUNT(a.Provider) desc, a.Apptdate desc)
    FROM Appointments a
    WHERE a.Apptdate BETWEEN DATEADD(YY, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
        AND a.FacilityId LIKE 2 --Perhaps this should be = instead of LIKE?
    GROUP BY a.PatientId
        , a.Provider
        , a.ApptDate
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: I'm new to sql and don't have any background in programing so I'm grateful for your response. This would work for one patient only correct? Would the ROW_NUMBER method be able to work with all patients seen in a timeframe? Sorry for not being clear!

Comment: No this would work for all patients. Notice that PatientID is one of the grouped columns.

Comment: So I just tried this and I'm only getting one row back. I put in the sql as listed above, I don't think it works to list all patients in a year.

Comment: Well it is limited to top 1 right so you will only get one row. Perhaps we need to explore using ROW_NUMBER to get the first value for each patient.

Comment: I think I got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about your question. please try this

```
select      b.PatientId,b.ResponsibleProvider,c.ProviderCount,c.MaxApptdate
from        ResponsibleProvider b
outer apply (SELECT     a.PatientId, a.Provider, COUNT(a.Provider) ProviderCount, MAX(a.Apptdate) MaxApptdate
            FROM        Appointments a
            WHERE       a.Apptdate BETWEEN DATEADD(YY, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
                        AND a.FacilityId LIKE 2
                        and b.PatientId = a.PatientId and b.ResponsibleProvider = a.Provider 
            GROUP BY    a.PatientId, a.Provider
            )c
```